# Firefox 35.0.1 and last don`t build on MacOSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, firefox, build

Try to build firefox from source codes without some changes. Just downloaded the sources, unpacked and try. I run bootstrap.py and it install all need. After that i run "./mach build". Building run 66 mins, after that says:

> 66:27.53   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
>
> 66:27.53   "_ures_getByIndex_52", referenced from:
>
> 66:27.53       icu_52::SimpleDateFormat::construct(icu_52::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_52::DateFormat::EStyle, icu_52::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) in libjs_static.a(smpdtfmt.o)
>
> 66:27.53       icu_52::DecimalFormatSymbols::initialize(icu_52::Locale const&, UErrorCode&, signed char) in libjs_static.a(dcfmtsym.o)
>
> 66:27.53       icu_52::openOlsonResource(icu_52::UnicodeString const&, UResourceBundle&, UErrorCode&) in libjs_static.a(timezone.o)
>
> 66:27.53       icu_52::TimeZone::dereferOlsonLink(icu_52::UnicodeString const&) in libjs_static.a(timezone.o)
>
> 66:27.53       _ucurr_forLocale_52 in libjs_static.a(ucurr.o)
>
> 66:27.53       _uprv_parseCurrency_52 in libjs_static.a(ucurr.o)
>
> 66:27.53   "_u_cleanup_52", referenced from:
>
> 66:27.53       JS_ShutDown() in libjs_static.a(jsapi.o)
>
> 66:27.53 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> 66:27.53 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> 66:27.53 gmake[5]: *** [jsapi-tests] Ошибка 1
>
> 66:27.53 gmake[4]: *** [js/src/jsapi-tests/target] Ошибка 2
>
> 66:27.53 gmake[3]: *** [compile] Ошибка 2
>
> 66:27.53 gmake[2]: *** [default] Ошибка 2
>
> 66:27.53 gmake[1]: *** [realbuild] Ошибка 2
>
> 66:27.53 gmake: *** [build] Ошибка 2
>
> 66:27.53 301 compiler warnings present.
>
> 66:27.61 /usr/bin/terminal-notifier -title Mozilla Build System -group mozbuild -message Build complete

I seen string "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" and go to build 32bit variant. Create .mozconfig:

> CC="clang -arch i386"
>
> CXX="clang++ -arch i386"
>
> ac_add_options --target=i386-apple-darwin9.2.0
>
> ac_add_options --enable-macos-target=10.5
>
> HOST_CC="clang-4.2"
>
> HOST_CXX="clang++-4.2"
>
> RANLIB=ranlib
>
> AR=ar
>
> AS=$CC
>
> LD=ld
>
> STRIP="strip -x -S"
>
> CROSS_COMPILE=1

And it build 33mins and show error:

> 33:13.84 clang: warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-tautological-constant-out-of-range-compare'; did you mean '-Wno-tautological-compare'?
>
> 33:13.86 warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-tautological-constant-out-of-range-compare'; did you mean '-Wno-tautological-compare'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
>
> 33:13.86 1 warning generated.
>
> 33:13.93 1 warning generated.
>
> 33:14.08 1 warning generated.
>
> 33:14.29 1 warning generated.
>
> 33:14.30 libgfx_cairo_cairo_src.a.desc
>
> 33:14.38 gmake[3]: *** [compile] Ошибка 2
>
> 33:14.38 gmake[2]: *** [default] Ошибка 2
>
> 33:14.38 gmake[1]: *** [realbuild] Ошибка 2
>
> 33:14.38 gmake: *** [build] Ошибка 2
>
> 33:14.39 94 compiler warnings present.
>
> 33:14.42 /usr/bin/terminal-notifier -title Mozilla Build System -group mozbuild -message Build complete

Tell me please, what can help me for build FF?
P.S. If i try build last sources from git i this result too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a strange answer, but I just started poking around in the firefox source and I notice this exact same build failure whenever I do a clobber build. If I proceed to ./mach build again without making any changes then the second build succeeds... *shrug* hope this helps